# Call a method before startActivity automatically

Tags: java, android, android-activity, reflection, android-source

I want a `method();` to be called automatically before each call to `startActivity(intent);` for the whole project because I cannot modify the other dependencies.

EDIT:

I found something called AOP using AspectJ

https://medium.com/@jdvp/aspect-oriented-programming-in-android-159054d52757

But I can intercept only my own app methods, Not the firmware startActivity()

Answer (score 0):

Call this `method()` in `onCreate()` assuming you're not using any flag to `startActivity`

Explanation:

Whenever an activity starts, the activity lifecycle by order is

`onCreate()` -> `onStart()` -> `onResume()`

EDIT:

Use a helper class `AppUtils.java`

```
public class AppUtils {

    public static void startActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent) {
        method(); // your method, you can put it inside AppUtils
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

then simply call `AppUtils.startActivity(intent)` from anywhere in your project. If your method needs a context, pass the activity context to it.

Comment: I want the method to be called before startActivity call not after, Lifecycle Callbacks are not a solution

Comment: you want to call it before startActivity()? where exactly? In the activity that have not started yet? :p

Comment: from a non activity context

Comment: Thank you, But startActivity is called multiple times in multiple dependencies that I don't own, using my own class is not a solution as well, I want to intercept startActivity method call

Comment: do you own all the activities being started?

Comment: If you don't, then you can do nothing about it, you will have to fork the projects and modify them accordingly. You want to intercept the Android framework and you can't do that, what you can do is only fork the projects or download them locally and change them (since they are open source)

Comment: Yes they are started from my app but I cannot modify all the external dependencies, They are big and some are obfuscated...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215209/discussion-between-alan-deep-and-hamza-ezzaydia).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do it in onCreate() method which executes before onStart(). OR
2. Use static method and run it before startActiviy().

Comment: I cannot do that because startActivity is called multiple times in multiple dependencies that I don't own, I want to intercept startActivity method call

Comment: What does the method do, that you want to execute it before ?

Comment: I want to add an intent flag before starting all the activities (Including the ones from external dependencies)